# Найти вершины дерева , через которые проходят наибольшее количество путей максимальной длины

Tags: алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

### Найти вершины дерева , через которые проходят наибольшее количество путей максимальной длины.

Функция этой задачи возвращает поддерево через которое проходят искомые вершины.

Понимаю как найти максимальный путь дерева, думаю , что нужно находить все максимальные деревья у левого и правого поддерева от исходного дерева. Но вот не могу понять как найти пересечения этих максимальных путей. Может изначально неправильно думал ,больше идей нет.

Answer (score 1):

1. Нашли максимальную длину пути
2. Обошли все пути максимальной длины, на каждом шаге увеличивая на единицу счетчик в узлах, через которые пробегаем
3. Выбрали узлы с максимальным счётчиком

Comment: Что, перестало работать? ;)